# Sizing a file from Blender to Shapeways

Tags: 3d-printing, dimensions

I have designed a model in Blender I want to print through Shapeways.

Here are the dimensions of the object in Blender, and the Scene's Units settings:

[image]

After import in Shapeways, the sizes are wrong:

[image]

When I fiddle around the Scale tool in Shapeways, I am still getting dimensions that are wrong (for example if I scale 10 000%, the dimension for Z will be 12.8cm but is 12.14cm on my model).

So I tried following [their guidelines](https://www.shapeways.com/tutorials/prepping_blender_files_for_3d_printing) "*scale your objects to the size you want, assuming 1 blender unit equals one millimeter*".

So, I click on Units > None and my dimensions become this:

[image]

So I type <kbd>S</kbd> **100** and I obtain this:

[image]

Which I think is what I want. So I upload the .STL file in Shapeways:

[image]

But after import the file is still given an imprecise/different size in Shapeways:

[image]

12.8cm on the Z axis while it should be 12.1cm.

Can I get Shapeways to print my model the exact size I want it?

Comment: Obvious question, but was the scale applied / changed by y and z axes ? (looks like scale by x is correct).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! In the first image you can see Scale: X/Y/Z: 1, after I applied scale it went to 1

Comment: Might be rotation is not applied and axes are reversed? Also: you can choose whether to use Y-up or Z-up in shapeways. Blender uses a Z-up coordinate system.